# C# Thread.Join() blocks the main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have 3 threads running: the main thread, the readData thread and the acquisition thread. From a form, when the play button is clicked, it starts the device acquisition and the readData threads. When the Stop button is pressed I wanna stop both threads. However, the acqusitionThread.Join() blocks the execution. What am I doing wrong?

Main Form

```
 private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          daqObj.Start();
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          daqObj.Stop();
        }
```

Data acqusition class to read the data from the device

```
     public void Start()
            {
                _isRunning = true;

            acquisitionDevice.StartAcquisition(); //starts thread for acquisition

                //start data acquisition thread
                _readDataThread = new Thread(readData);
                _readThread.Name = "Read data Thread";
                _redThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
                _readThread.Start();
            }

       public void ReadData()
        {

            try
            {
                // write data to file
                while (_isRunning)
                {
                    //Reads data (dequeues from buffer)
                    float[] data = acquisitionDevice.ReadData(numValuesAtOnce);

                    //Do other stuff with data (eg: save to file)
                }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", ex.Message);
                }
    }


            public void Stop()
            {
                _isRunning = false;

                    if ((_writeToFileThread != null) && _writeToFileThread.IsAlive)
                        _writeToFileThread.Join(); //stop readData thread

                    acquisitionDevice.StopAcquisition(); //stops acquisition thread

                     Console.WriteLine("acquisiton thread stopped); //THIS IS NEVER EXECUTED

            }
```

Device acqusition class:

```
 public void StartAcquisition(Dictionary<string, DeviceConfiguration> deviceSerials)
        {
            //ensure that data acquisition is not already running
            if (_isRunning || (_acquisitionThread != null && _acquisitionThread.IsAlive))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Data acquisition is already running!");

            _isRunning = true;

            //initialize buffer
            _buffer = new WindowedBuffer<float>(BufferSizeSeconds * sampleRate * totalChannels);

            //start data acquisition thread
            _acquisitionThread = new Thread(DoAcquisition);
            _acquisitionThread.Name = "DataAcquisition Thread";
            _acquisitionThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
            _acquisitionThread.Start(deviceSerials);
        }

 public void StopAcquisition()
        {
            //tell the data acquisition thread to stop
            _isRunning = false;

            //wait until the thread has stopped data acquisition
            if (_acquisitionThread != null)
                _acquisitionThread.Join(); //THIS BLOCKS

            Console.WriteLine("ended"); //THIS IS NEVER EXECUTED
        }
```

**EDIT**
Instead of a separate thread for reading the data, I do it inside a token cancellation. I use a separate thread for data acquisition form the device (this is needed to continuously get data) and then I read it and write it to a file with a token cancellation.This is the code that works:

```
public void StartAcquisition()
            {
                // Initialize token
                _cancellationTokenSourceObj = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var token = _cancellationTokenSourceObj.Token;

                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
               {

                   // Start acquisition
                   try
                   {
                       // Write device configuration parameters to .txt file
                       System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(deviceConfFilePath);
                       file.WriteLine(gUSBampObj.GetDeviceConfigurationString());
                       file.Close();

                       // create file stream
                       using (_fileStream = new FileStream(daqFilePath, FileMode.Create))
                       {
                           using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(_fileStream))
                           {
                               // start acquisition thread
                               deviceAcquisition.StartAcquisition();

                               // write data to file
                               while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                               {
                                   float[] data = deviceAcquisition.ReadData(numValuesAtOnce);

                                   // write data to file
                                   for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                                       writer.Write(data[i]);
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", ex.Message);
                   }

               }, token)
           .ContinueWith(t =>
           {
               //This will run after stopping, close files and devices here

               // stop data acquisition
               deviceAcquisition.StopAcquisition();

           });


                }
            }

public void StopAcquisition()
{
    _cancellationTokenSourceObj.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what `Join()` does.  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: You need some way to interrupt `ReadData()` (which is presumably a blocking call)

Comment: Why does it not return? Why Console.WritLine("ended"); is never executed if the thread is finished?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for Thread.Join()? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What do you think `Join()` does? Why do you think the thread is finished?

Comment: You may also want to look up what the `volatile` keyword does: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to block and wait for the other thread to finish.  That is what Thread.Join() does.

Instead you would want to perform a thread cancellation.  [MSDN Managed Thread Cancellation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If I wanna write to a file, can I do it inside a thread cancellation? That's what I implemented before but then it was no writting all values to the file.

Comment: You can do whatever you want.  Just make sure to flush the stream and close before accepting the cancellation.  Otherwise some data won't be written.

Comment: BTW: C# 4.0 in a Nutshell has a very good threading section which Joseph Albahari [made available online](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).  It is a very useful resource.

Comment: This is what I implemented in a thread cancellation. However I am not correctly writing to the file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33087368/write-to-file-inside-a-thread-cancellation

Comment: In this case you are using Task not Thread.  You may want to use Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();   Otherwise your code looks reasonable.

Comment: However it does not write the values correctly to the file. Is it possible that is because of the flush()?

Comment: The using clauses should call the Dispose() on each object, for streams, this should also call Close(), which SHOULD call Flush().  It wouldn't hurt to add a flush before ThrowIfCancellationRequested(), and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.Join()` is, by design, a blocking call, from the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Join is a synchronization method that **blocks the calling thread** (that is, **the thread that calls the method**) until the thread whose Join method is called has completed. Use this method to ensure that a thread has been terminated. **The caller will block indefinitely if the thread does not terminate.**

(Emphasis mine)

So this is by design, since you don't call one of the overloads with a timeout. However your code has another problem, you might not be signaling the thread to terminate like you think.

Thats where the [`volatile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx) keyword comes in, you should declare your `isRunning` field with it, like so:

```
private volatile bool _isRunning;
```

This will ensure that the compiler does not use single-threaded cache optimizations on the field value, and fetches the latest value each time that field is read. Since you are updating that field from multiple threads, you need to mark it as `volatile`.

The other problem you have is your `while` loop:

```
while (_isRunning)
{
    //Reads data (dequeues from buffer)
    float[] data = acquisitionDevice.ReadData(numValuesAtOnce);

    //Do other stuff with data (eg: save to file)
}
```

The problem is this line:

```
float[] data = acquisitionDevice.ReadData(numValuesAtOnce);
```

If that is a blocking call, and `ReadData` doesn't return, no matter what you set `_isRunning` to, it will never terminate the thread until that method returns.

You should look into the [Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) and cancellable tasks, raw threads are becoming depreciated for higher level control. Also consider [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) instead, since you are doing blocking I/O, really no reason for a new thread to sit and wait for I/O when you can just await an I/O bound task.