# Write to file inside a thread cancellation

Tags: c#, multithreading, io

I wanna write to a file the values I am constantly reading from my acquisition device. My app consists of a presentation, which is a form that contain 2 boxes that change color every 1 second. In parallel, I am reading data form my acquisition device and writing its values to a file. However, these values are only written every 1 second instead of constantly. How should I write to a file? Do I need a separate thread?
This is the code for acquisition:

```
public void StartAcquisition()
            {
                // Initialize token
                _cancellationTokenSourceObj = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var token = _cancellationTokenSourceObj.Token;

                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
               {

                   // Start acquisition
                   try
                   {
                       // Write device configuration parameters to .txt file
                       System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(deviceConfFilePath);
                       file.WriteLine(gUSBampObj.GetDeviceConfigurationString());
                       file.Close();

                       // create file stream
                       using (_fileStream = new FileStream(daqFilePath, FileMode.Create))
                       {
                           using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(_fileStream))
                           {
                               // start acquisition thread
                               deviceAcquisition.StartAcquisition();

                               // write data to file
                               while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                               {
                                   float[] data = deviceAcquisition.ReadData(numValuesAtOnce);

                                   // write data to file
                                   for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                                       writer.Write(data[i]);
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", ex.Message);
                   }

               }, token)
           .ContinueWith(t =>
           {
               //This will run after stopping, close files and devices here

               // stop data acquisition
               deviceAcquisition.StopAcquisition();

               // Close file
               // _fileStream.Flush();
               //_fileStream.Close();

           });


                }
            }

public void StopAcquisition()
{
    _cancellationTokenSourceObj.Cancel();
}
```

**EDIT**
As pointed in the comments, the code is correct and works. The problem was related to the ReadData() function.

Comment: You should not use multi threading when you are writing to files, as it could cause conflicts such as "File in use". That is my opinion.

Comment: File I/O and multi-threaded code work fine together. If you do it correctly. As for your question, there's nothing here that would explain why your file I/O happens only on 1 second intervals. From the code you posted, it's clear that the file will be written to every time the `ReadData()` method returns. But do keep in mind that `FileStream` is buffered, so not every call to `Write()` results in data being sent to the disk.

Comment: It's also possible you have somehow accidentally synchronized the `ReadData()` method with your once-per-second UI update, but without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces your problem, it's not possible to know for sure even whether that's the actual problem, never mind explain how to fix it.